# TableLayout with scrolling vs GridView vs Listview with list item

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm confused in 3 ways that I can to do what I want to do. I want to do a list of items that it's looks like:

first row : a TextView and a a EditText.

second row : a TextView and a a EditText.

... and repeat the sequence n-times that contains information from database.

We can use a TableLayout with scrolling or a Gridview or a ListView with adapter but... What's better in term of efficiency? What is the best way to do this?

Thanks.